# How to code turtles avoiding pop. densities at certain patches

Tags: netlogo, behavior, agent

I am trying to create a sub-model in NetLogo in which my turtle agents avoid/flee urban patches that have a human density greater than the agents' tolerance threshold. The objective of this model is to experiment with the human-density variable to see how/if my turtles move in response to higher or lower human populations.

I am having extreme difficulty in conceptualizing how I can implement the human-population variable into the individual urban patches and have the patch calculate its own human-density. I would like to have the option of changing the human population variable so that I can see how the turtle responds to the changing human density at the urban patches.

To give a hypothetical example: There are two urban patches (cities) in a state county, Urban_1 has an area of 600m while Urban_2 has an area of 200m. The human population at both urban patches are 100 people, and thus the human density at Urban_1 is 0.16 people/m2 and the human density at Urban_2 is 0.5people/m2. The turtle tolerance threshold is <0.4 humans/m2.

How can I code the human population variable so the population densities can increase/decrease? Is the human population variable a global variable? Or is it an agentset of the urban patches?

Comment: This is very confusing. If you have 100 patches, do you want 100 sliders on the interface that each provide the population for one patch? I assume not. But what is it that you actually want the slider to control?

Comment: Hello. I apologize for the confusion. I would like to apply the human-population variable to all the patch-type "urban" and then be able to adjust the human-population in the Interface. My goal is to show how the avoidance behavior changes as the human pop. increases/decreases.

Comment: Still not explicit enough. You say in your question that turtle agents flee patches that have a higher human density. If the human-population is controlled by ONE slider and that number is given to all the patches, how can some of your patches have higher or lower density? You probably need to edit your question to provide an example with numbers of how you want to get from whatever is on the slider to whatever is owned by the patches.

Comment: @JenB thank you for your feedback. I have edited my question in hope that it can clarify what I am trying to code.

Comment: You have a fundamental misconception about NetLogo patches - they are all the same size. If you want them to represent different geographical sizes, you can assign them some arbitrary dimensions as a patch-own variable. However, this will not change their actual shape in any way so, for example, the wrong patches will be next to each other.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your input and time @JenB. I am fairly new to NetLogo and still trying to understand how the software can be implemented for my research questions. I will try again tomorrow (:

Comment: No problem. NetLogo is pretty easy to learn and there's lots of excellent resources available (see the main NetLogo site for tutorials for example). StackOverflow is set up as a Q&A site that helps you resolve errors in your code. The format doesn't work (and isn't intended to) for back and forth discussion needed for teaching. The best option is to try it out and then show your code when it doesn't work as you expect or generates an error. That's the sort of thing we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

To see the human population density or growth you to plot in the GUI more or less like this: `plot count human`. Nice things to do is to differentiate the types of agent with different turtles-own group. In order to avoid some turtles to go above a particular kind of patches you need to create a patches-own variables and then do like this: `patches-own [ ... feromone-killer ] ... to wiggle if (feromone-killer >= 0.01)`
(To wiggle is a method that determinate the movements of my agents)